# Best way to abbreviate income ranges

Tags: abbreviations

I'm looking for recommendations on how best to abbreviate the following demographic income range:

> *1 below 3,000,000 Japanese yen (JPY)
>
>   2 between 3,000,000 and 4,999,999 JPY
>
>   3 between 5,000,000 JPY and 7,999,999 JPY
>
>   4 8,000,000 JPY and above*

Would it be correct to rewrite as:

> *1 below 3M JPY
>
>    2 between 3M and 4.9M JPY
>
>   3 between 5M and 7.9M JPY
>
>   4 8M JPY and above*

Should the M for million be in caps or lower case, and should there be a space between the number and the m?

Comment: You have a problem in that 4,999,995 is neither between 3M and 4.9M, nor between between 5M and 7.9M, although that's not really an English problem. I think you're better off saying _at or above 3M and below 5M_ for the second band, and _at or above 5M and below 7M_ for the third.

Comment: I think it sounds rather weird to say, for example, *"I have below a million pounds"*. Certainly in the UK we'd be much more likely to say *"I have **less than** a million pounds"*. Much the same applies to *above/more than* on the other side of the cutoff amount.

Answer (score 2):

There is a yen symbol you know, - ¥.

When I worked in Japan we would present numbers that looked something like this: ¥ 3.7 million.

So I would set out your categories as follows:

1. Below ¥3.0 million
2. More than ¥ 3.0 but less than ¥ 5.0 million
3. More than ¥ 5.0 but less than ¥ 8.0 million.
4. Over ¥ 8.0 million.

Comment: Given that all your tenths digits are 0, is there any compelling reason to use _3.0_ and _5.0_ as opposed to _3_ and _5_?

Comment: @J.R. it depends on the actual context and the purpose of the report. However, I find it useless here, because the ranges are obviously made up by someone just to make a nice report. If it were some financial report, or monthly accounting paperwork, then the digits after the decimal point would make sense, but I don't think the reader of this kind of stats will anyhow care about JPY .05 that someone missed, especially that JPY does not have coins of decimal value (like USD cents), the smallest amount is ¥1.

Comment: @J.R. Probably not. But as a veteran of 40 years behind an accountant's desk, I always like to establish some basis for levels  of detail and set a pattern for how one wants numbers reported. When I call my bank, before I am able to select from the menu, a lady's voice slowly tells me the balance on my account, down to the last penny. It is meaningless, and I could in any event get it online. So many people in business get bogged down with numerical detail that often the important message gets lost.

Comment: WS2 is totally correct.  You're establishing a level of precision. It's the appropriate, let's say, level of precision when dealing with salaries in the millions/yen range.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, for the position of the currency code itself, I found this interesting piece on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217):

The ISO standard does not regulate either the spacing, prefixing or suffixing in usage of currency codes. According however to the European Union's Publication Office, in English, Irish, Latvian and Maltese texts, the ISO 4217 code is to be followed by a fixed space and the amount:

> a sum of EUR 30

In Bulgarian, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, Estonian, Finnish, French, German, Greek, Hungarian, Italian, Lithuanian, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian, Slovak, Slovene, Spanish and Swedish the order is reversed; the amount is followed by a fixed space and the ISO 4217 code:

> une somme de 30 EUR

As for the prefix, M is the correct one, I guess it is because in metric (SI) prefix system M (Mega) denotes 10^6 (6th power of 10), and m (milli) - 10^-3. And there should be a space between the number and the prefix.

Finally, if you are not using these statistics in literature, you can use simple notation:

1. < JPY 3 M
2. JPY 3 M - JPY 5 M
3. JPY 5 M - JPY 8 M
4. > JPY 8 M

Though with the currency symbol (¥) instead of ISO code, as @WS2 suggested, it looks better.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to say is

```
1 up to 3m yen
2 up to 5m yen
3 up to 8m yen
4 over 8m yen
```

It's Just That Simple.

(Of course, use the yen symbol, JPY, yen, Yen, or whatever is appropriate.)

Personally I would use the "m" lower-case m, because it looks better. ("International standards" etc are utter crap and you can ignore them.)

Comment: I downvoted for several reasons. • *m* is an abbreviation for *milli*, not *mega*. • The four classes *1 up to 3M*, *2 up to 5M*, etc overlap each other.  Eg,  *2 up to 5M* contains all of *1 up to 3M* except for 1.  •  Saying “It's Just That Simple” when the answer is wrong is not useful.

Comment: "M" is an "official" metric SI abbreviation, and is appropriate in certain usage. It's inappropriate here. The fact that the four classes overlap in a - let's say - exacting mathematical sense, is totally irrelevant. It's the usual shorthand for exactly this multiple choice question.